# Where is the proper place to put JSON parsing code in iOS 5 project?

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am a noob of iOS development. Now I have a project that parses a JSON file on the web server and displays the content  on iPhone screen. In the tutorials the parsing codes are all in a view controller. In my project, however, four or five screens use the contents from the same JSON file. Is it a better way to put all the parsing code into a separate class with class methods and use class methods to parse the content in different view controllers? Or is it better to use protocols for parsing JSON and implement the protocols in the view controllers for different content needs?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail your situation? e.g. When the JSON is downloaded, are all the view controller that uses the data have already instantiated or will they be instantiated later? How many instances of this JSON data do you expect at one time?

Comment: In fact the questions you asked me are also questions in my mind. I think it might be good to instantiate them before all screens are available although I really have no experience in doing this. I also don't know whether it is best to get multiple instances of JSON data or always keep one during runtime.

Comment: I think I'm not clear enough on my second question. What I mean to ask is: does all of your screens use the same JSON data at one time (in which case Singleton pattern may apply), or do they use different JSON data? tl;dr Can you apply Singleton to the JSON data?

Comment: I see. The majority of the screens use different JSON data at one time. Maybe at some point two of them share the same data.

Comment: You can create a separate class to store the data and do the parsing like what I suggested in my answer below. As for sharing... Can you identify which screen will share with which? If you can, then you can just access the data directly, or push the data to the other screen (possibly segue, or delegation, etc.). If you cannot, or the "sharing" behavior is all over the place, you have to somehow create a "management" kind of class to cache the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class that parses and store the information from the JSON and share the class between different view controllers. Downloading the JSON may be done in other class. This is only the overall idea, though.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put the download JSON codes? The tutorial I read put them in ViewDidLoad of the view controller so when the screen loads the JSON gets downloaded. If I were to put them in other class where should I put them? Do I still need to load JSON on every screen or just load it once on the very first screen?

Comment: @newguy: It depends. viewDidLoad as you mentioned is one alternative. If you are certain that one screen is always loaded before another, and both uses the same JSON data, then you can pass the JSON or read the JSON from the other view controller. The most flexible but also troublesome is to create a "manager" kind of class, where the view controller request for the JSON, and the "manager" will give existing JSON data or create new by downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting all the parsing into its own class  - this way code isnt reimplemented umpteen times, you just allocate the class and feed it some data and either give it a delegate that follows a certain protocol and tell the delegate the info found when parsed or feed the parser class a block `^{}` to be called when the parser is done. Look at NSXMLParser, I feel as though you are doing a similar thing but JSON instead of xml

Answer (score 0):

In it's own class in a 'Utilities' group perhaps? Also, if you are looking into JSON parsing, be sure to check [NSJSONSerialization class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)